# sql server query to get records from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables in sql server and I want result like below -

[image]

There is a column LabelName in both the tables. And I need records on the basis of that column. There are two tables for two different languages with same LabelName.

So can any one help me out on this.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Did you actually add the join tag? Then, why not at least try to search for joins and their syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` for that with some `CASE`, to get the result, look at: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp and  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

So what you need is this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN e.LabelId IS NULL THEN t.LabelId ELSE e.LabelId END AS LabelId
, CASE WHEN e.LabelName IS NULL THEN t.LabelName ELSE e.LabelName END AS LabelName 
, e.LabelText AS LabelText_English
, t.LabelText AS LabelText_Tamil
FROM TBL_English AS e
FULL OUTER JOIN TBL_Tamil AS t ON e.LabelId = t.LabelId
```